# PHP String stripped and stored

Tags: php, string

I have a long string that I want everything from the first "-" on to be removed and the remaining saved.
I have tried rtrim and this does not work. can figure explode so that will not work

Comment: use explode function and you should show some sample string

Comment: paste your string here

Comment: Show your string and what you have tried so far

Comment: Share your code script.

Comment: 3568206020-1201103628-13107292-0001 this is the string.

Comment: echo rtrim($str, "-");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
$str = "3568206020-1201103628-13107292-0001";
//extract the substring from start to the first occurrence of the character `-`.
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "-"));
```

Output - `3568206020`